# Python decimal and import: How to use ROUND_UP without 'import *'?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I begin to learn Python, the [Idiomatic Python style guide](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#importing%20%5B) strongly suggests never using `from module import *`, stating that it is a bad habit.

I am trying to use the decimal package to round up numbers. How can I round up numbers without having to use "from decimal import *"? Even the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for decimal uses "from decimal import *"!

I tried the following, among other things:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import decimal

print "UPDATE: Price is %s" % (decimal.Decimal(4233/3600).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.000001'), round=ROUND_UP))
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "./calculate_hourly_stats.py", line 4, in 
>       print "UPDATE: Price is %s" % (decimal.Decimal(4233/3600).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.000001'),
>   round=ROUND_UP)) NameError: name 'ROUND_UP' is not defined

In decimal.py, ROUND_UP is a constant. How do I import constants from decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing special about the `decimal` module here - `ROUND_UP` is just another name in it, same in that way as `Decimal`.  So you could say `decimal.ROUND_UP`.  Or

```
from decimal import ROUND_UP
```

and then use plain `ROUND_UP`.

By the way, something else in the docs is common practice in programs that use `decimal` heavily:

```
from decimal import Decimal as D
```

Then you can write, e.g., D("1.23") instead of `decimal.Decimal("1.23")`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already imported `decimal`, refer to the constant as `decimal.ROUND_UP`.

There's also nothing wrong with `from decimal import ROUND_UP`. The style guide is warning against blindly importing everything, not against importing specific names.